How to calculate average per month when I know the daily roster?
I have a table that contains the daily roster for each staff
I have a measure that calculates the daily count
Staff rostered = 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK('Staff rosters'[staff_key]),
        FILTER('Staff rosters', 'Staff rosters'[Rostered type] = "Contact"
        )
    )


I want to use the measure to display monthly average per centre when selected a centre, and average across the organisation when nothing is selected. How can I do that? When I use the measure with the month-year, then I get total staff rostered over the month not an average. It is okay when I am looking at organization wide
I have created a summarized table
Rostered Contact Staff = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        SUMMARIZE(
            'Staff rosters',
            'Staff rosters'[Date rostered],
            'Staff rosters'[centre_key],
            "Staff Count", DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK('Staff rosters'[staff_key]),
            "Month", FORMAT('Staff rosters'[Date rostered], "MMM-YYYY")
        ), 'Staff rosters'[Rostered type] = "Contact"
    )

I have a measure in the summarized that does the trick
Average Count = 
  VAR AvgCount = AVERAGE('Rostered Contact Staff'[Staff Count])

  RETURN
  IF (
    HASONEVALUE(Organisation[Kindergartens]), 
    AvgCount, 
    SUMX(
        VALUES(Organisation[Kindergartens]), 
        AvgCount)
  )

I am keen not to create a separate table and do this within the table

Can you add some sapmle data and the result you want to achive?
